# CIFS mount in fstab succeeds on IP, fails on hostname written in /etc/hosts

Tags: ubuntu, mount, cifs, fstab, domain-name-system

I wonder why my Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS has problems resolving a hostname from fstab.
I tried to mount the following entry:

```
//NAS-5h2-20/backuppc/  /mnt/backuppc   cifs   auto,user=THEUSER,password=THEPASSWORD,cifsacl,uid=109      0       0
```

the mount fails with the error

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //NAS-5h1-15/backuppc,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
   need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

and the Syslog entry:

```
Unable to determine destination address.
```

HOWEVER, this works like a charm if I exchange the hostname **NAS-5h2-20** for its IP **192.168.1.29**. However, for portability reasons, I'd like to map the mount by hostname within the fstab.

Contents of **/etc/hosts** is (among other lines):

```
192.168.1.28    NAS-5h1-15
192.168.1.29    NAS-5h2-20
192.168.1.30    NAS-6h1-04
```

These Hostnames are not registered with the local DNS-Server. And it's intended do be in some cases able to use different IPs (servercluster/workstation) for DNS and server-internal usage, so I can't register them to the DNS.

It's also no Problem to

```
ping NAS-5h2-20
```

.

Thus I'm sure, it's a  resolver problem. However, I can't figure out, where.
I look at nsswitch.conf, nothing special there:

```
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
hosts:          files dns
networks:       files
protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
netgroup:       nis
```

And */etc/resolv.conf* also looks OK:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.1.1
search ourdomain.local
```

So, questions:
- why does the resolver fail to read OR ignores the hosts file **in this special case?**
- is DNS/WINS/ some other resolving method hardcoded into mount.cifs?

Comment: From http://askubuntu.com/a/374699: `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, the samba (cifs) package on some distributions doesn't use the hosts file to resolve the name. Instead, it uses the NetBIOS name to resolve to the IP. There are two ways to go about this:

- Set samba to use the hosts file for resolution.

In your smb.conf file, find and modify or create the following line:

```
    [global]
    name resolve order =  host lmhosts wins bcast
```

and restart samba. This will set samba to a use a standard host name to IP address resolution, using the system /etc/hosts, NIS, or DNS lookups, to resolve the server name. Additionally, added `machine-name.domainname` as an alias in your hosts file:

```
    192.168.1.28    machine-name    machine-name.domainname
```

- Set the NetBIOS name of the machines you are trying to connect to.

On the machines you're trying to connect to set the following in the smb.conf file:

```
    netbios name = MachineName
```

and restart samba.

---

Ideally, you want to do both of these things, however just setting samba to use the hosts file should work.

References:
https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch07.html

Comment: Tiksi, do you have any ideas how to change this setting without installing the samba package on the machine? Currently speaking, only cifs-utils is installed and would like to avoid installing additional packages only to be able to resolve DNS addresses. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to get this to work with auto.misc, but something was missing.

Installing cifs-utils package and then restarting autofs fixed it.

More details (as requested)...

I use autofs to mount external (network) resources as required.

So, I install autofs, together with samba.

Then I have an entry like this in `/etc/auto.misc`:

```
REMFOLDER -fstype=cifs,ro,username=user,password=PW ://windowsbox.my.local.domain/SHAREDFOLDER
```

That means I can access the SHAREDFOLDER on the windowsbox as `/misc/REMFOLDER`.

This has worked well for years.

However, on a new installation of Pop OS (based on Ubuntu) and version 21.04, this was not working.

I could use `smbclient` with the username and password to access the SHAREDFOLDER, but the `auto.misc` entry was not working.

The message indicated (sorry, didn't note it down) that the username/password was incorrect.

A search led me to here, and the solution that worked was to install the `cifs-util` package.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I've updated.  Is that enough information?

Comment: Is that a typo in the last sentence? The package is actually called `cifs-utils`? Or is `cifs-util` a different package?

Answer (score 3):

Same symptom noted on a vanilla install of Ubuntu 22.10, but quickly resolved by installing `cifs-utils`:

```
james@pi-desktop:~$ sudo mount -t cifs //rc-kvm2.somewhere.com/musicLibrary /home/james/Music -o credentials=/home/james/.smbpass_music
[sudo] password for james: 
mount: /home/james/Music: mount(2) system call failed: No route to host.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

```
james@pi-desktop:~$ sudo dmesg
[...]
[  508.219069] CIFS: Unable to determine destination address
[...]
```

```
james@pi-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
[...]
The following NEW packages will be installed
  cifs-utils keyutils
[...]
```

```
james@pi-desktop:~$ sudo mount -t cifs //rc-kvm2.somewhere.com/musicLibrary /home/james/Music -o credentials=/home/james/.smbpass_musiclibrary
james@pi-desktop:~$
```

Sorted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For me, this also was the solution to this problem occurring on Ubuntu 22.04.